# Why my chrome browser automatically gets resized in the mid of execution of my automation script?

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation

I have a selenium automation script for my project that runs daily on a Windows server machine on chrome browser (in full screen mode) and it gets triggered via Jenkins job. Now, on that machine, automation scripts for other projects are also running.

Sometimes what happens is that my browser gets resized automatically in the middle of execution of my code and the test cases get fail (because WebElement becomes non-interactable). Once my browser gets launched I maximize it immediately as I want my test cases to be executed on the full screen window. Please suggest what could be wrong.

```
driver.manage.window.maximize();
```

Expected Result - Browser window should not get minimize in the mid of execution of automation code.

Actual Results - My browser window gets minimized in the mid of execution of my automation script sometimes.

Comment: Are you using remote driver?

Comment: No. I am not using Remote Driver. I am using WebDriver.

Comment: So, is just a test in your local machine? Show us your code in order to help you. Maybe you can create a minimal demo code.

Comment: Minimized or resized? Any 3th party SW pop-up when Chrome gets resized/minimized?

Comment: @JRichardsz This was actually occurring on windows server machine(not my local). But now it seems fine. Thank you.

Comment: @pburgr Resized. No such 3rd party SW popup. This might be due to some issue on the windows server machine where the script is executing. Now it is working fine. Thank you.